# Is it possible to change the target device family of an App in an App-Store?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, stored-procedures, app-store

I have an published app in store for iPhone and iPad. I just created v.1.0 for iPad and iPhone wrongly. I want to change target device just for iPhone for new version.

And iTunes gives me an error: "Change your target device family."

Is there a way to publish just for iPhone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not submit only for iPhone using universal settings, as your binary contains setting for both iPhone and iPad.

You will need to submit new binary with updated `Deployment Target` for iPhone.

[Similar question has been asked over here also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229507/mistakenly-submitted-ios-app-as-universal-how-to-change-post-publish). - Not sure if link makes sense.